# Cómo concatenar literales y variables en twig

Tags: php, twig

Estoy habituado a presentar literales y variables en twig utilizando construcciones del tipo:

```
<p>Hola {{ usuario }} bienvenido a mi web</p>
```

Pero hay veces que necesito introducir el resultado previamente en una variable, por ejemplo para poder reutilizar el título de la página, ¿cómo hago en ese caso para concatenar literales y variables? He probado esto pero no funciona:

```
{% set title = "Perfil del usuario: " + usuario %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En twig el **operador de concatenación** es `~`:

```
{% set title = "Perfil del usuario: " ~ usuario %}
```

También se podría usar directamente en salida a pantalla:

```
{{ "Perfil del usuario: " ~ usuario }}
```

Cualquier variable que se invoque en una construcción de este tipo se convierte directamente en una cadena:

```
{% set goles_betis = 2 %}
{% set goles_sevilla = 2 %}
{% set resultado = "Betis: " ~ goles_betis ~ " / Sevilla : " ~ goles_sevilla %}
```

Por último existe otro método muy interesante: el **operador de interpolación**. Éste permite introducir y evaluar expresiones dentro de cualquier cadena siempre que vayan dentro de comillas dobles (al estilo de PHP)

```
{{ "Betis: #{goles_betis} / Sevilla: #{goles_sevilla}" }}
{{ "Goles totales: #{goles_betis + goles_sevilla}" }}
```